# Library for logging Call Stack at runtime (Windows/Linux)

Tags: c++, windows, linux, debugging

I need a way to record the function stack trace in a debug log to help me diagnose a defect. The problem is that I need to implement this on Windows and Linux using C++.

After a little research, I have found that:

- For the Windows implementation, I can use [StackWalk64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680650%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API function and family.
- Under Linux, I have found [libunwind](http://www.nongnu.org/libunwind/docs.html) that sounds great.
- Or, I can use glibc's [backtrace](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/glibc/libc_665.html)

Before starting work, I want some advice if this is the right way and to ask if there is an already written multi-platform library that can help. I suspect that I'm not the first programmer who needs this. :)

Comment: +1 for a good question well asked !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Google Breakpad](http://code.google.com/p/google-breakpad/) handles all of this for you if you want to get crash dumps back from the field.

Comment: A crash dump contains much more information then I need. And should be post processed - this is a big inconvenient. I simply need the stack trace as a string or an array of strings.

Comment: You have to postprocess unless you're willing to ship private PDBs along with your app, and a minidump is around the size of a large JPEG.

Comment: shipping private PDBs is not a problem.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote 2 articles about this topic, including Googles breakpad as well as a very thin self written approach that works for windows and linux:

Postmortem Debugging - http://drdobbs.com/tools/185300443

Post-Mortem Debugging Revisited - http://drdobbs.com/architecture-and-design/227900186

Answer (score 1):

Some years ago I wrote this: http://drdobbs.com/cpp/191100567

Basically some macros log the place where the stack unwind happens when an exception is thrown.

An updated version of the framework can be found in the library Imebra (http://imebra.com)

Comment: you are referring to FUNCTION_START/ FUNCTION_END macros ?

Comment: Yes. They catch and rethrow and log the passage of the exception.